# How to write a batch file calling sqlcmd to query SQL Server and if instance unreachable, it would echo the server name to a log file?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

The idea is to write a batch file to execute a query against a list of SQL servers and get some information from them, if any SQL Server is not reachable, I want this batch file to write `servername\instancename` to a text file for my reference.

I have around 100 SQL Server instances (in text file), when I get the result, it is hard to know which instance was unreachable during the batch file execution.

This is the script I use to get the info from the SQL Servers in (listed in text file) and it works:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (SQLLIST.txt) do sqlcmd -E -h -1 -W -M -S %%S -i C:\Foldername\Query.sql >> Destination\QueryResult.csv -s ","
```

I figure I may need to add an IF statement to do that? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE** I do not have `Sqlcmd` on this device, so not able to test this.

I would say using `-b` switch to get `errorlevel` This should simply `echo` to screen the instance and `errorlevel` `0` is success and `1` is error:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (SQLLIST.txt) do (
    sqlcmd -b -E -h -1 -W -M -S %%S -i C:\Foldername\Query.sql >> Destination\QueryResult.csv -s ","
    echo %%S !errorlevel!
)
```

So you could log it to file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (SQLLIST.txt) do (
    sqlcmd -b -E -h -1 -W -M -S %%S -i C:\Foldername\Query.sql >> Destination\QueryResult.csv -s ","
    echo %%S !errorlevel!
 )
)2>&1>mysqlcmd.log
```

or log it to seperate

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (SQLLIST.txt) do (
    sqlcmd -b -E -h -1 -W -M -S %%S -i C:\Foldername\Query.sql >> Destination\QueryResult.csv -s ","
    echo %%S !errorlevel!
 )
)2>&1>mysqlcmd.log
```

Or you can specify success or failure:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(for /F "tokens=*" %%S in (SQLLIST.txt) do (
    sqlcmd -b -E -h -1 -W -M -S %%S -i C:\Foldername\Query.sql >> Destination\QueryResult.csv -s ","
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 set outp=Success
    if !errorlevel! equ 1 set outp=Failed
    echo %%S !outp!
 )
)2>&1>mysqlcmd.log
```